# How to do google signin without login screen.

Tags: ios, google-signin

We need access token with google silent login. Don't want to show login screen. We want to do login in the background.

Comment: I don't think this is possible bcoz  where to you think the user will give the input for the google account credentials ??

Comment: Can we use rest api for login like webservice?

Answer (score 3):

In any social media login integration, we get access token by signing to that media and for that it is required to authenticate user using login page of that media. And then we get access token with all given information of that social media like google sign In, facebook sign in and twitter login etc.

Comment: Can't we  use Rest Api Like Paypal?, Can't we do the same by using Url?

Answer (score 1):

You always need the users consent the first time he signs in.